# private variable are not object specific if i use for loop in constructor : JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am facing a weird problem, just look at following code..

```
var ApplicationParser = (function(){

ApplicationParser.prototype.messageFramer;
ApplicationParser.prototype.isPreviousFetchingDirection;
ApplicationParser.prototype.latestDataArrays = [];
ApplicationParser.prototype.dataPointsArray = [];
ApplicationParser.prototype.chartObject;
ApplicationParser.prototype.titleLabel;
ApplicationParser.prototype.chartConfiguration;
ApplicationParser.prototype.htmlId;

function ApplicationParser(url,dataPointArray, title, htmlId,fetchSize) {

    this.messageFramer = new MessageFramer(url,fetchSize);
    this.isPreviousFetchingDirection = true;
    this.messageFramer.FetchNextData(this,this.isPreviousFetchingDirection);

    this.dataPointsArray = dataPointArray;
    this.titleLabel = title;
    this.htmlId = htmlId;

    for (var int = 0; int < globalConfiguration.length; int++) {
        var array_element = globalConfiguration[int];
        this.latestDataArrays[array_element] = new Array();

    }
}
return ApplicationParser; }());
var app1 = new ApplicationParser('url',dataPointArray,title,"#context", 50000);

app1.latestDataArrays = [1,2,3];
app1.dataPointsArray = [1,2,3];

var app2 = new ApplicationParser('url',dataPointArray,title,"#context", 50000);

app2.latestDataArrays = [4,5,6];
app2.dataPointsArray  = [4,5,6];
```

Now if you try to access 'latestDataArrays ' of both object then it will show [4,5,6]; while 'dataPointsArray  ' remains different. why 'latestDataArrays ' is also not able to show different values...

Where as if i replace above code with following then the problem is getting solved...

```
var ApplicationParser = (function(){

ApplicationParser.prototype.messageFramer;
ApplicationParser.prototype.isPreviousFetchingDirection;
ApplicationParser.prototype.latestDataArrays = [];
ApplicationParser.prototype.dataPointsArray = [];
ApplicationParser.prototype.chartObject;
ApplicationParser.prototype.titleLabel;
ApplicationParser.prototype.chartConfiguration;
ApplicationParser.prototype.htmlId;

function ApplicationParser(url,dataPointArray, title, htmlId,fetchSize) {

    this.messageFramer = new MessageFramer(url,fetchSize);
    this.isPreviousFetchingDirection = true;
    this.messageFramer.FetchNextData(this,this.isPreviousFetchingDirection);

    this.dataPointsArray = dataPointArray;
    this.titleLabel = title;
    this.htmlId = htmlId;

    var latArrayTemp = new Object();

    for (var int = 0; int < globalConfiguration.length; int++) {
        var array_element = globalConfiguration[int];
        latArrayTemp[array_element] = new Array();

    }
    this.latestDataArrays = latArrayTemp;
}

return ApplicationParser;}());
```

Please tell what is the reason behind it, is it the for loop inside constructor creating problem, if yes then why...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please tell what is the reason behind it, is it the for loop inside constructor creating problem?**

No, it has nothing to do with the for loop. The root cause of the problem is:

`dataPointsArray` is the instance variable of `app1` and `app2` -- each `ApplicationParser` object will have its own unique `dataPointsArray` instance.

However, `latestDataArrays` is a field in `ApplicationParser.prototype`, which means all `ApplicationParser` objects (`app1` and `app2`) will share the `latestDataArrays` instance (unless they declare that it's `latestDataArrays` point to something else. This is exactly the behavior of your second code snippet).

**How to fix the problem?**

As `dataPointsArray` and `latestDataArrays` is instance variable, please remove them from `ApplicationParser.prototype`. That is, remove the following 2 lines:

```
ApplicationParser.prototype.latestDataArrays = [];
ApplicationParser.prototype.dataPointsArray = [];
```

---

Some detail explanation:

**What happens in the code: `var app = new ApplicationParser(...)`?**

When `new ApplicationParser(...)` is called, the following steps are executed:

1. An empty object is created and extends from `ApplicationParser.prototype` . Let's call it X.
2. Execute the function `ApplicationParser` (the constructor), using X as `this` inside the function.
3. If there is no `return` statement inside the constructor, return X;
4. Assign X to `app`.

**What happens for `app1` and `app2`?**

For `var app1 = new ApplicationParser(...)` statement, let's call its "X" as Xapp1.

For `var app2 = new ApplicationParser(...)` statement, let's call its "X" as Xapp2.

After Xapp1 is created and BEFORE the constructor is running, `Xapp1.dataPointsArray` points to `ApplicationParser.prototype.dataPointsArray` and `Xapp1.latestDataArrays` points to `ApplicationParser.prototype.latestDataArrays`:

```
Xapp1.dataPointsArray === ApplicationParser.prototype.dataPointsArray // true
Xapp1.latestDataArrays === ApplicationParser.prototype.latestDataArrays // true
```

After Xapp1 is created and AFTER the constructor is running, `Xapp1.dataPointsArray` points to a new object (the corresponding parameter, let's call it as D1) and `Xapp1.latestDataArrays` still points to `ApplicationParser.prototype.latestDataArrays`, as it is not re-assigned, `this.latestDataArrays[array_element] = ...` only changes some property of the object that `this.latestDataArrays` point to.

```
Xapp1.dataPointsArray === ApplicationParser.prototype.dataPointsArray // false, as Xapp1.dataPointsArray is D1 now.
Xapp1.latestDataArrays === ApplicationParser.prototype.latestDataArrays // true
```

For Xapp2, the logic is the same, so:

```
Xapp2.dataPointsArray === ApplicationParser.prototype.dataPointsArray // false, as Xapp2.dataPointsArray is D2 now.
Xapp2.latestDataArrays === ApplicationParser.prototype.latestDataArrays // true
```

Thus, it is clear that Xapp1 and Xapp2 share the object of `latestDataArrays`, but their `dataPointsArray` is unique.

**Why the second code snippet works?**

The second code snippet works because of the following statement:

```
this.latestDataArrays = latArrayTemp;
```

This statement re-assign the `latestDataArrays` field, making Xapp1's `latestDataArrays` point to a new object (let's call it L1), and Xapp2's `latestDataArrays` point to another (L2). Thus:

```
Xapp1.latestDataArrays === ApplicationParser.prototype.latestDataArrays // false, as Xapp1.latestDataArrays is L1 now.
Xapp2.latestDataArrays === ApplicationParser.prototype.latestDataArrays // false, as Xapp2.latestDataArrays is L2 now.
```

This makes Xapp1 and Xapp2's `latestDataArrays` unique.

Comment: but how does the problem get slved as long as i took out the latestDataArrays  out of loop

Comment: The problem is solved because: in the code `this.latestDataArrays = latArrayTemp;`, `this.latestDataArrays` is pointed to a new object.

Comment: But `dataPointsArray` is also defined on the `ApplicationParser.prototype` object , shouldn't it also be shared between instances ?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia `dataPointsArray` is overwritten in the constructor :) Please note the code: `this.dataPointsArray = dataPointArray;`

Comment: @Puneet, `dataPointsArray` is not getting shared. It's not shared because it is already been pointed to a new object in constructor.

Comment: @shaochuancs if you see i also tried to override `latestDataArrays` in first code

Comment: To solve the problem, you can remove the code `ApplicationParser.prototype.dataPointsArray = [];`. I'll edit my answer and include this information.

Comment: @shaochuancs Oh, I see, didn't saw that.

Comment: @Puneet in the first code snippet, `this.latestDataArrays[array_element] = new Array();` does not override `latestDataArrays` -- `this.latestDataArrays` still point to the same object

Comment: @Puneet I've edited my answer, together with some detail explanation. Please check and let me know if there are any further questions.

Comment: @shaochuancs , No now its clear... thank you so much again

Comment: @Puneet Glad to hear that. If the problem is solved and this answer is helpful, maybe it can be accepted? :)

Comment: Accepted sir, sorry for delay